# How do I install easy_install?

Tags: python, easy-install

I am doing a project for a class in Python and I am a very inexperienced programmer and terrible with computers.  Is there a simple way to install easy_install so I can use the classes from the package coinor.blimpy from https://pypi.python.org/pypi/coinor.blimpy/1.0.0   ?? I have Windows. I have tried Googling it but none of the directions I have seen make any sense. Can someone give me easy and detailed step-by-step instructions?

Answer (score 1):

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools#windows

> The recommended way to install setuptools on Windows is to download ez_setup.py and run it. The script will download the appropriate .egg file and install it for you.

Answer (score 1):

You could try pip instead of easy_install. You can get a Windows binary of pip here: http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/

Once you have pip installed, you can probably just do:

```
pip install coinor.blimpy
```

If Windows doesn't find pip for you, it should be in the Scripts directory of your Python installation, e.g. `c:\Python27\Scripts`.

If you must use easy_install (I'd rather not--pip works better), I think you find it as part of `setuptools`.